# C# MySQL database related

Tags: c#, mysql, database

What I want to achieve is to input data into MySQL database automatically from my first form.

Right now, I can only input data into the database when I click on this form. How do I save all my data automatically in the first form without me clicking every form to save the data? Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

```
        RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser;
        rk = rk.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\TypedURLs", false);
        PrintKeys(rk);
        rk.Close();

        void PrintKeys(RegistryKey rk)
        {
        if (rk == null)
        {
            richTextBoxBrowsing.Text = "Browsing history is empty!" + "\n";
            return;
        }

        richTextBoxBrowsing.AppendText("Subkeys of " + rk.Name + "\n");

        try
        {
            string[] valnames = rk.GetValueNames();

            foreach (string s in valnames)
            {
                //int i = richTextBoxBrowsing.SelectionStart;
                string val = (string)rk.GetValue(s);
                richTextBoxBrowsing.AppendText("-----------------------------------------------" + "\n");
                richTextBoxBrowsing.AppendText(s + "\n");
                richTextBoxBrowsing.AppendText(val + "\n");

                //create a MySQL connection with a query string
                MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection("user id=root; password=qwerty123456; database=syscrawl; server=localhost");

                //open the connection
                myConn.Open();

                MySqlCommand myCommand = myConn.CreateCommand();

                myCommand.CommandText =
                "insert into browsing_history (unique_id, url)"
                + " values "
                + "('" + s + "', '" + val + "')";

                MySqlDataReader myResult = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

                //close the connection
                myConn.Close();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception MyError)
        {
            richTextBoxBrowsing.AppendText("An error has occurred: " + MyError.Message + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hm... some context could help. From what you've said it sounds like the code posted happens in an onClick even on your form(s)?

If you just want it to happen right away when the form loads, then put your code in the onLoad event of the form instead (double click on the form title bar to get to the onLoad event).

If that's not enough, please be more detailed/specific as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have a few of these forms that contains data. I want to place all the data into MySQL database automatically without having to click every form. From what you had said, to put in the onLoad event, this means that I can only input data only when i click that form.

Comment: @athgap: It might be easier to provide a solution if you described the way your application is laid out. You might want to create an object whose concern it is to write data to your database, then have an instance of that object on each form. In each form, you can have a timer that will periodically call the requisite method(s) on that object to insert data into your database.